# How can I get CRM 2011 duplicate detection on new records to look at ALL records?

Tags: duplicates, dynamics-crm-2011, detection

Now it only sees duplicates if they own the duplicate record. I don't want to give reps permission to see or change other people's records but want those possible duplicates to appear in duplicate detection so the reps don't add another record for the same lead.

Answer (score 5):

Your requirements conflict. If you don't give your reps Read access to those other records, technically they shouldn't even know about duplicates. From a security perspective, that would be allowing the user to Read something they shouldn't Read, e.g. knowing that another record already exists with this name.

You have two out-of-the-box options: Give the reps Read access to each other's Leads or run duplicate detection jobs.  Duplicate detection is broken into two methods: Proactive and Reactive. You are speaking of Proactive - you don't want the system to even allow a duplicate to be created. But if you can't relax your security requirements, you'll need to move to Reactive - this entails creating a duplicate detection job that will run on a schedule and you'll need to assign a person to review those jobs and merge duplicate records.

If neither of these are acceptable, you'll need to go with Daryl's option of creating a plugin. But that is a lot of work compared to your other two options.

Comment: +1 for mentioning my answer.  j/k.  +1 for the reactive method.  I'd forgotten about that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of the issue you're describing with the duplicate detection only able to check for records the user has access to.  Put if that is indeed a limitation, you'd have to create your own custom plugin on the validation stage that would run as an elevated user account, to check for duplicates and throw an exception if a duplicate is found.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers above sum it up nicely. If the workers cannot see the other records then de-dup will not find them.

I would give them access but with R/O rights to other user / teams records.

In places where i've had this issue I use the audit trail also to keep track of anyone loading records they should not, even if they are read only. This does however need a simple bit of on-load script to set a field to trigger audits as the in built audit tool does not monitor access.

Comment: Another way around this is to create a new 'shadow' entity with just the basic info from a client record. Everyone can have R/O access to this and you can use a workflow to create a new shadow client record automatically on adding of a normal client. Then simply create de-dup rules between the client and shadow client...